# Javascript/jQuery string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, string

I'm trying to either grab only part of this URL or inject part of a string into it (whichever is simplest).

Here's the URL:

```
http://www.goodbuytimeshare.com/listings/min:1000/max:150000/agreements:rent,buy/properties:apartment,condo,hotel,resort/show:4/
```

I figure I either need to be able to tim it down to:

```
/listings/min:1000/max:150000/agreements:rent,buy/properties:apartment,condo,hotel,resort/
```

Or turn it into:

```
http://www.goodbuytimeshare.com/listings/ajax/min:1000/max:150000/agreements:rent,buy/properties:apartment,condo,hotel,resort/show:4/start:1/end:100/
```

(Same URL but "ajax/" would be added after the ".com/")

Which of these would be simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, use regex!

```
var myString = "http://www.goodbuytimeshare.com/listings/min:1000/max:150000/agreements:rent,buy/properties:apartment,condo,hotel,resort/show:4/";
var matches = (/^http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+(\/.+)$/).exec(myString);
var mySubString = matches[1];
```

Although, [now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is non-regex solution. Of course regex is succinct.

```
var original = "http://www.goodbuytimeshare.com/listings/min:1000/max:150000/agreements:rent,buy/properties:apartment,condo,hotel,resort/show:4/";

// split into an array of separate fields

var fields = original.split("/")

var results = "";

for (i=0;i < fields.length;i++) {
// Insert ajax/ in the fourth position

if (i == 3) {
   results += "ajax/";
}

results += fields[i] 

// don't put the slash on the last item

if (i < (fields.length -1)) {
   results += "/";
}
}

// write out the results and append more

document.write(results + "start:1/end:100/");
```